# Souvenir stamps on old/cancelled passport

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, passports, passport-stamps

I made a huge mistake during my recent trip. I got the 3 souvenir stamps on my canceled passport and then realized that I might still need my old passport for future travel.
I still have valid long-term US/Canada and UK visas in that passport.

How likely will it impact my future travels to these countries? I am aware that unauthorized stamps could be considered tampering. Is there any way to fix this issue or should I already apply for the new visas?

Comment: Is any of the souvenir stamps on any of the valid visas or on the adjacent pages?

Comment: No, they aren't.

Comment: I suspect you're probably fine in that case, but if you're prone to worry you might want to get new visas just to put your mind at ease.

Comment: Is it very obvious? A "Hello Kitty" stamp or something like that?

Comment: op has not returned to clarify. vote to put on hold.

Comment: it's "somewhat" obvious